# Finish() to go back two activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity A that calls Activity B for a result.

Activity be calls the camera intent to take a picture then sends it off to a server.  On the PostExecute method of the async task of Activity B I call finish() hoping to get back to activity A.  However the image I have just received from the intent call of Activity B gets removed.  I have to press the back button again to get back to activity A.

How can I skip the middle activity of getting a picture from the camera and return to activity A?

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: Is starting the camera and sending the picture the only thing that Activity B does?

Comment: no it basically is an input form that fires off a camera intent, gets the image back and sends the form data and image to a web server.  I have figure this out see below :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if anyone is interested i used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivityForResult(i, key);
```

Comment: what happen if i only need  two activities ?